# UIAlertController --> Used to update variable?

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I'm new to Xcode and Swift. I'm trying to set up an alert (which I have done - code below). I was wondering if someone can help me out. What I would like to do is reset two different variables to 0 if "Yes" is tapped.

Your help is greatly apprecieated.

```
@IBAction func showAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm Point Reset", message: "Are You Sure?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: nil)

    let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Default, handler: nil)


    alertController.addAction(firstAction)
    alertController.addAction(secondAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the completion handler and update the values in that closure. The completion handler is the code that is executed when the action occurs (when the button is pressed).

```
let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action in
    self.foo = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to:
            let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action in
            count = 0
            }      and then I get a "Reference to property 'count' in closure requires explicit 'self' to make capture semantics explicit

Comment: In closures, you cannot omit the `self.` for non-local variables so just change it to `self.count` and it should work

Comment: Thank you! Last question after is it possible to add another action? I would like to update a label. I thought I could do the following but it does not work:    @IBAction func showAlert() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm Point Reset", message: "Are You Sure?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        
        let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action in
            self.count = 0
            self.blueScoreLabel.text = "\(self.count)"
                 }  --> The label is not updating

Comment: Same problem, add self.  for blueScoreLabel and count and line breaks would help